# How to draw a 3D curve using ListPointPlot3D with continuously changing colours?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

I have a list of points in the form of

```
data = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, ......, {xn, yn, zn}}
```

and I can draw a 3D curve using the data using the command

```
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.01], Line[data]}, Axes -> True].
```

However, I would like to have the colour of the curve changing continuously using a colour map. 
Basically I want a result similar to what one can do with `ParametricPlot3D`. For instance,

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, ColorData["Rainbow"][t]]]
```

produces an output like below:

[image]

How can I do the same thing when I have the data as a list of points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
pnts = N@Table[{Cos[t], 0, Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}];
pnts[[All, -1]] = Rescale[pnts[[All, -1]]];
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.01], 
  Map[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Mean[#[[All, -1]]]], Line[Most /@ #]} &, 
   Partition[pnts, 2, 1]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of "continuously changing colours" using [`CirclePoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html) , [`VertexColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html) and [`Hue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hue.html)

### [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)

```
ListAnimate@With[
  {
   n = 30
   },
  Table[
   Graphics3D[
    {Thick,
     Line[
      Append[#, First[#]] &[
       Prepend[0] /@ CirclePoints[n]
       ]
      , VertexColors -> RotateLeft[Array[Hue, n + 1, {0, 0.8}], k]
      ]
     }
    ],
   {k, n}
   ]]
```

[image]

### [`ListPointPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html)

```
ListAnimate@
 With[
  {n = 50},
  Table[
   ListPointPlot3D[
    List@*Prepend[0] /@ CirclePoints[n]
    , PlotStyle -> RotateLeft[Array[Hue, n + 1, {0, 0.8}], k]
    , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
    ]
   , {k, n}]
  ]
```

[image]